# Why am I getting the error message "TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have the following `T-SQL` query. However, it is giving me an error message when executed.

The error message is :

```
Msg 1014, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value.
```

My `T-SQL` query stands as follows:

```
;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d)

INSERT INTO Allot4

SELECT
       b.Date as [TDate],
       Season,
       RN,
       TAProfileID,
       TOName,
       Market,
       RoomType,
       Property,     
       TOType

    FROM Allot3 a
    CROSS APPLY
    ( 
      SELECT top(datediff(d,Datefrom,case when DateTo >= DateFrom
                 then dateadd(d, 1, DateTo) else DateFrom end))
        DATEADD(d,row_number()over(order by 1/0)-1, DateFrom) Date
      FROM tally
    ) b
```

What's wrong here and how do I solve it?

Comment: Do we have `null` value in these columns (`DateFrom` and `DateTo`) of `Allot3` table ? If yes, then `null` value inside `TOP` clause is creating this issue.

Comment: Add Isnull inside Top clause - `SELECT top(isnull(datediff(d,Datefrom,case when DateTo >= DateFrom then dateadd(d, 1, DateTo) else DateFrom end)),0)`

Comment: @BhatiaAshish Thanks. I found one row where all the values were NULL.
Please post as an answer and I'll give it my vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When we specify expression inside `TOP` clause, we have to make sure that expression when evaluated should not return `NULL`. I have added `ISNULL` inside your statement -

```
;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT 1 FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d)

INSERT INTO Allot4

SELECT
       b.Date as [TDate],
       Season,
       RN,
       TAProfileID,
       TOName,
       Market,
       RoomType,
       Property,     
       TOType

    FROM Allot3 a
    CROSS APPLY
    ( 
      SELECT top(isnull(datediff(d,Datefrom,case when DateTo >= DateFrom
                 then dateadd(d, 1, DateTo) else DateFrom end)),0)
        DATEADD(d,row_number()over(order by 1/0)-1, DateFrom) Date
      FROM tally
    ) b
```

We can read more about `TOP` clause from -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql